# parsing JSON to Pandas without prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below JSON which is returned from an API call.

I want to put it in a Pandas dataframe, but when I do it doesn't work because it's prefixed by '{"apps":{"app":[' and it just outputs a bit 'ol string in one column.

```
{"apps":{"app":[{"id":"application_1589431105417_21534","user":"udsldr","name":"HIVE-61a4ee14-1d26-4c7b-bf0d-1cc2a990557d","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21534/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294649069,"finishedTime":1590294666011,"elapsedTime":16942,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn150.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21534_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn150.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":144531,"vcoreSeconds":17,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21535","user":"nifildr","name":"HIVE-850812d7-9d22-4be8-a225-7b341f6ea980","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21535/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294664397,"finishedTime":1590294801090,"elapsedTime":136693,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn129.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21535_01_000001/nifildr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn129.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":18279340,"vcoreSeconds":4248,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21532","user":"udsldr","name":"HIVE-73e0c359-32a5-4334-89da-4a8ae2bb1037","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21532/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294622244,"finishedTime":1590294643808,"elapsedTime":21564,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn35.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21532_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn35.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":182247,"vcoreSeconds":22,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21533","user":"udssupport","name":"tcs.uds.webstats","queue":"udssystem","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21533/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294631138,"finishedTime":1590295670552,"elapsedTime":1039414,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn148.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21533_01_000001/udssupport","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn148.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":4762538052,"vcoreSeconds":775756,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21530","user":"nifildr","name":"HIVE-e9a64e12-11f0-4ba8-b069-3be0ce561137","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21530/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=3, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294606965,"finishedTime":1590295033193,"elapsedTime":426228,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn75.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21530_01_000001/nifildr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn75.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":114397555,"vcoreSeconds":27175,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21531","user":"nifi","name":"HIVE-a063ddd1-5bf8-47b4-8ce3-8497c93b79a5","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21531/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294613578,"finishedTime":1590294655173,"elapsedTime":41595,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn56.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21531_01_000001/nifi","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn56.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":345792,"vcoreSeconds":42,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21528","user":"udsldr","name":"com.cardinality.LocationDB","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21528/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"5ec9f8480000f1697e683969","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294605875,"finishedTime":1590294782281,"elapsedTime":176406,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn167.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21528_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn167.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":43389139,"vcoreSeconds":5239,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21529","user":"keenek1","name":"Clean DPI Report","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21529/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294607111,"finishedTime":1590295032105,"elapsedTime":424994,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn62.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21529_01_000001/keenek1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn62.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":2114077299,"vcoreSeconds":344079,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21542","user":"murugaa1","name":"HIVE-a1a5aadb-254c-4289-ad22-e9c7ce5e9814","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21542/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590295275713,"finishedTime":1590295297948,"elapsedTime":22235,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn46.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21542_01_000001/murugaa1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn46.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":999465,"vcoreSeconds":217,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21543","user":"murugaa1","name":"HIVE-cdc8a5da-f880-4f8e-9baf-b306095b9efb","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21543/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590295277611,"finishedTime":1590295301515,"elapsedTime":23904,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn41.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21543_01_000001/murugaa1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn41.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":1077860,"vcoreSeconds":228,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""}]}}
```

So I tried this but it doesnt edit it.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

```
import os
command = "curl 'http://52.18.29.01:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/?limit=10'"

out = os.system(command)
out2 = str(out).replace('{"apps":{"app":[', '').replace(']}}', '')
print(out2)
```

Comment: How are you getting the json?  Are you using pandas or requests?

Comment: your json is missing some closing braces. please fix

Comment: it's just an OS curl request using the OS library

Comment: I've now added the full log - I didn;'t know if anyone would want all that detail!

Comment: JSON.loads on 'out' gets this error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: S... Tat is because os.system returns exit code of the command executed, not the command output.

Comment: if I print out, it shows the JSON - it does provide the whole command output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import subprocess
import json
import pandas as pd

# os.system return's the executed command exit code, not the command output.
command = "curl 'http://52.18.29.01:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/?limit=10'"
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

# output of subprocess will be bytes, converting to string.
if isinstance(output, bytes):
    output = output.decode()

output = json.loads(output)
pd.DataFrame(output['apps']['app'])
```

---

As pointed by @NYC Coder using request module.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://52.18.29.01:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/?limit=10')

if r.status_code == 200:
    pd.DataFrame(r.json()['apps']['app'])
```

Comment: Ahh thanks dude. Its rare that a stack overflow answer works straight away, but this did - you're awesome

Comment: As mentioned by @NYC Coder, that would be the right way to do instead of using curl as it is platform dependent command.

Comment: I tried that, but it failed with some other error 'TypeError: expected string or buffer'

Comment: Thanks! Ah because its a flexible schema, all the columns are misaligned. Is there a way to map JSON columns to DF columns?

Comment: @kikee1222, u might need to ask new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do this:

```
res = requests.get('http://52.18.29.01:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/?limit=10')
data = res.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data['apps']['app'])
print(df)

                                id        user                                       name  ... logAggregationStatus unmanagedApplication amNodeLabelExpression
0  application_1589431105417_21534      udsldr  HIVE-61a4ee14-1d26-4c7b-bf0d-1cc2a990557d  ...            SUCCEEDED                False
1  application_1589431105417_21535     nifildr  HIVE-850812d7-9d22-4be8-a225-7b341f6ea980  ...             TIME_OUT                False
2  application_1589431105417_21532      udsldr  HIVE-73e0c359-32a5-4334-89da-4a8ae2bb1037  ...            SUCCEEDED                False
3  application_1589431105417_21533  udssupport                           tcs.uds.webstats  ...             TIME_OUT                False
4  application_1589431105417_21530     nifildr  HIVE-e9a64e12-11f0-4ba8-b069-3be0ce561137  ...             TIME_OUT                False
5  application_1589431105417_21531        nifi  HIVE-a063ddd1-5bf8-47b4-8ce3-8497c93b79a5  ...            SUCCEEDED                False
6  application_1589431105417_21528      udsldr                 com.cardinality.LocationDB  ...             TIME_OUT                False
7  application_1589431105417_21529     keenek1                           Clean DPI Report  ...             TIME_OUT                False
8  application_1589431105417_21542    murugaa1  HIVE-a1a5aadb-254c-4289-ad22-e9c7ce5e9814  ...            SUCCEEDED                False
9  application_1589431105417_21543    murugaa1  HIVE-cdc8a5da-f880-4f8e-9baf-b306095b9efb  ...            SUCCEEDED                False
```